# Mailjet Template API: Add attachments to template

Tags: api, templates, mailjet

I want to add inline images to my transactional email templates.
I can't find on the [official API](https://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/template-detailcontent/) a way to push attachments for a template.

I've tested with the following parameters :

```
{
    "ContentType": "image/png",
    "Filename": "image.png",
    "Base64Content": "base64code"
}
```

The API doesn't recognize the property : `Properties not supported in JSON payload`

I don't to attach my image each time I send the email using Send API.

Is there any way to attach files to a Mailjet Template.

Regards,
Clément

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible to insert an attachment in the template. Attachments should be provided in each transactional API call.

Comment: Do you know if this is still not possible? And so we cannot add a custom image in the mail HTML, without providing an external URL for src? Thanks.